# Import over 50 000 products to woocommerce, takes more than 4 hours

Tags: wordpress, performance, woocommerce, import

Im going nuts trying to solve this problem, been working on this for 2 weeks now. I would appreciate all help.

Im having a issue with importing over 50 000 products from a xml file to woocommerce.
The xml parsing is fast, working in less than a few minutes but the "import part" to woocommerce is very slow.

I tried wordpress/woocommerce rest api and that was a big no, too slow.
So now im using a PHP file on the server that parse the xml files and uploads them.

I get the XML file in this format:

```
 <product>
    <SKU>28760</SKU>
    <Name>...</Name>
    <Description>...</Description>
    <Category>...</Category>
    <Price>...</Price>
    <Shipping>...</Shipping>
    <Currency></Currency>
    <Instock>yes</Instock>
    <ProductUrl>...</ProductUrl>
    <ImageUrl>...</ImageUrl>
    <Brand>...</Brand>
    <OriginalPrice>...</OriginalPrice>
    <Ean>...</Ean>
    <ManufacturerArticleNumber>...</ManufacturerArticleNumber>
  </product>
```

Then when parsing im using XMLReader for this, pushing each element/row to temporary array and then calling the import function with that array.

Here is how it functions:

1. Bash scripts run php import.php > run.log
2. Import file starts, xml parsing is fast but importing is slow and goes slower when reaching about 2000 products.

Im using the class WC_Product_Variable to create a new product.

Here is my function "import($p, $coId, $coName)" where $p is product, $coId companyId and $coName company name from where I got the xml file.

```
    try {
        $product_exists = wc_get_product_id_by_sku($p->SKU . "-MAIN");

        if ($product_exists !== 0) {
            $product = wc_get_product($product_exists);
            $log->info('Product already exists, skipping', ["SKU" => $p->SKU . "-MAIN"]);
        } else {
            $product = new WC_Product_Variable();
            $product->set_name($p->Name);
            $product->set_sku($p->SKU . "-MAIN");
           
            $category = (string)$p->Category;

           
            $categories = explode(" - ", $category);
            $parent_id = 0; 
            foreach ($categories as $cat) {     
                $term = term_exists($cat, 'product_cat', $parent_id); 
                if (!$term) {
                    $term = wp_insert_term(
                        $cat, mn
                        'product_cat', 
                        array(
                            'parent' => $parent_id 
                        )
                    );
                }

                // New category id
                $parent_id = $term['term_id'];
            }

            // Upload image to wordpress
            $image_url = $p->ImageUrl;
            $image_id = media_sideload_image("{$image_url}", 0, null, "id");

            if (is_wp_error($image_id)) {
                echo "Error uploading image \n";
            } else {
                $product->set_image_id($image_id);
            }

            $product->set_category_ids(array($parent_id));

            $attributes = array();

            // one available for variation attribute
            $attribute = new WC_Product_Attribute();
            $attribute->set_name('Company');
            $attribute->set_options(array("{$coName}"));
            $attribute->set_position(0);
            $attribute->set_visible(true);
            $attribute->set_variation(true);
            $attributes[] = $attribute;

            $attribute = new WC_Product_Attribute();
            $attribute->set_name('Brand');
            $attribute->set_options(array($p->Brand));
            $attribute->set_position(0);
            $attribute->set_visible(true);
            $attribute->set_variation(false);
            $attributes[] = $attribute;

            $product->set_short_description((string)$p->Description);
            $product->set_attributes($attributes);
            $product->set_regular_price($p->OriginalPrice);
            $product->set_sale_price($p->Price); 
            $product->set_stock_status("outofstock");
            $product->save();

            $insertTag = wp_set_object_terms($product->get_id(), $p->Brand, "product_tag", true);
            if (is_wp_error($insertTag)) {
                echo "Cant insert tag for product: " . $insertTag->get_error_message() . " \n";
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $log->error("Can't create main product", ["Error" => $e->getMessage(), "Product SKU" => $p->SKU]);
    }

    try {
        // now we need two variations for Magical and Non-magical Wizard hat
        $variation = new WC_Product_Variation();
        $variation->set_parent_id($product->get_id());
        $variation->set_sku((string)$p->SKU . "-" . $coId);
        $variation->set_attributes(array('company' => $coName));
        $variation->set_regular_price((string)$p->OriginalPrice);
        $variation->set_sale_price((string)$p->Price);
        $variation->set_stock_status(($p->Instock == "no" ? "outofstock" : "instock"));
        $variation->update_meta_data("brand", (string)$p->Brand);
        $variation->update_meta_data("updated", (string)Date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
        $variation->save();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $log->error("Can't create variant product", ["Error" => $e->getMessage(), "Product SKU" => $p->SKU]);
    }

    // Check memory and CPU usage
    $load = sys_getloadavg();
    $memory_usage = memory_get_usage(true);




    if ($load[0] > 1.5 || $memory_usage > 0.9 * $memory_limit) {
        $logger->warning('Current memory and CPU usage - PAUSING 10 SEC', [
            'loadavg' => $load[0],
            'memory' => $memory_usage . " of " . $memory_limit,
        ]);
        sleep(10); // Pause 10 seconds
    }
```

Any ideas how I can make it faster?
Right now it takes about 4 hours to import 25 000 products.

Im using a VPS with 4GB ram, 2 CPU.

Other than this function this is whats included in my file before the function:

```
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);


require_once "vendor/autoload.php";

if (!defined('ABSPATH')) {
    define('ABSPATH', '/opt/bitnami/projects/****/public_html/');
}
include_once ABSPATH . 'wp-load.php';
include_once ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/class-wp-error.php';
include_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php';
include_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php';
include_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php';
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php');



use Monolog\Logger;
use Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler;

$memory_limit = ini_get('memory_limit');
if (preg_match('/^(\d+)(.)$/', $memory_limit, $matches)) {
    if ($matches[2] == 'M') {
        $memory_limit = $matches[1] * 1024 * 1024; // nnnM -> nnn MB
    } else if ($matches[2] == 'K') {
        $memory_limit = $matches[1] * 1024; // nnnK -> nnn KB
    }
}

// Create a logger
$log = new Logger('import');
$log->pushHandler(new StreamHandler('/opt/bitnami/projects/****/logs/import-' . Date("Y-m-d") . '.log', Logger::INFO));
$log->info('Init import', ["Status" => "Starting up"]);


// Log the current memory and CPU usage
$logger = new Monolog\Logger('import-usage');
$logger->pushHandler(new Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler('/opt/bitnami/projects/****/logs/import-' . Date("Y-m-d") . '.log', Monolog\Logger::DEBUG));



echo "Start import job... \n";
```

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you add timestamp logs after each step? Also, I see you have sleep(10) in your code, how often is that executed?

I think the problematic part is image download. Can you try to import without calling wp_sideload_image? Depending on your image size and location, this step is probably the longest. Maybe you can do this in another step, before running import, you download all images to your server and then just attach them during the import process. Does this makes sense?

Comment: I could add timestamp after each step, for now im logging each xml feed when it started and ended. Would timestamp be better?
I did try without wp_sideload_image - but I did not see any difference sadly.

Each import gets to 20-25 000 products after 4 hours, then I suspect memory issue taking place making the import stop or stall.

Sleep is executed based on the avg cpu load after each product import, so it checks if cpu is more than 150% or memory more than 90% then sleep(10) gets triggered.

Comment: Yes, I would add timestamps to locate the bottleneck. Some ideas:
 - instead of checking ` $term = term_exists($cat, 'product_cat', $parent_id); ` insert all categories before running import, it will save some time
 - `wc_get_product_id_by_sku()` - before import make a list of products which are already in the database and then skip the check. You can create a temporary table with SKU / product_id and check there instead of calling `wc_get_product_id_by_sku()` .

Comment: I tried your suggestions above, the image import was stalling with ~ 2 seconds on each import. Made a difference to remove it and save it for later. But still, on average a product import is made in about 1 second to 0.8 ms , making it 13 hours to import 50k products.
I think the issue is the class itself WC_Product_Variable being slow. 
I Will try to change the method of checking if product exists aswell.
The alternative way would maybe be direct to database but i cant find any schema och relationship declaration for woocommerce/wordpress. Any suggestions?

Comment: I would not recommend importing directly into the database. Finding sku could be slow, try to measure that part

Comment: Thanks, I removed all products, removed check sku before inserting (if products exists). Started import, made a bit difference, making about 2-3 products per second. Making the whole import between 4-7 hours. Ay more suggestions? My CPU and memory is not high at all, running about 40%. Thinking maybe of executing several bash scripts that imports different files and the same time instead, maybe that would make it faster. I can see that saving process for variant product is slow aswell.

Comment: You could remove `term_exists` and insert check if you insert all categories before. So, parse all files and pull out the list of categories, then create all categories before product insert. Then you can skip the check. You can also try parallel import as you suggested

Comment: Decided to go with magento, making it much faster. I have come to conclusion that Wordpress is not made for this heavy duty projects. Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: How long it takes to import the same data to Magento?

Comment: Not yet done with my script, but for now about maximum 2 hours. Also there is bigger support in the community and already plugins in place that helps you on the way. The biggest difference is the VPS power needed to handle magento but its OK if it gets the job done.

Comment: @Chris would be interested to chat to you sometime as I have a similar issue. Processing around 10 CSV product feeds varying from 1k to 200k products in each. I'm filtering some rows out and then either updating or importing the remaining products. My total sync runs through around 300k products and takes under 45mins locally and around 2 hours on my VPS. Also memory usage is relatively high for what seems a basic task. Are you contactable?